# Suitescript fill subsidiary in item

Tags: restlet, suitescript2.0

In Suitescript 2.1 I'm trying to create an inventoryitem.
But I'm getting this subsidiary error.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try and create the exact same item in the UI. Log all of the values that are being set in the script and set them with the same values in the UI in the *same order* that they are being set in the script. 
In theory it is possible the subsidiary is inactive but that is just a wild guess.

Comment: I adjusted a parameter in the function to view all subsidiaries and it worked!